# F# Converting Currency from Excel

Tags: excel, f#, currency

I'm trying to convert a column in an Excel sheet to a float in my F# application. The problem is that I do not know in which format the currency is supplied. This can be manually typed, with or without a symbol and of course the . and , symbols are always a mess.

Is there any "short and sweet" way of warsing a what appears to be incohesive array of possibilities to an actual floating point value which later after some arithmetic can be printed as currency?

A side problem I've encountered:
When a column in Excel is marked as *Number* 600.00 will be exported through the interop libraries as 600; 534.20 will be exported as 534.2
A simple parse on the . symbol is not enough.

The symbol which is not shown is Excel will be exported through the interop libraries as a *?* (with a space following).

These options do not wor:

```
let ParseFloat1 (o:obj) =
    float (o.ToString())


let parseFloat2 (o:obj) =
    float (System.Single.Parse(o.ToString()))
```

After these attempts I just went crazy and started *russamafuzzin'* solutions, not even this dragon of a bad idea worked:

```
let ParseFloat o =
    // ugly 
    let mutable _string = o.ToString()

    // because of the weird "lets leave trailing zero's off behavior
    let changeString (s:string) =
        match s.LastIndexOf "." with
        | 0 | -1 -> s + "00"
        | 1 -> s + "0"
        | _ -> s

    _string <- changeString _string

    let characters = _string.ToCharArray()
    // remove all the non numbers from the string
    let rec parse source dest =
        match source with
        | h::t -> 
                  match h with
                  | '1' | '2' | '3' | '4' | '5' | '6' | '7' | '8' | '9' | '0' -> parse t (dest + h.ToString())
                  | _ -> parse t dest
        | _ -> dest

    let _float = parse (Array.toList characters) ""
    let result = (float (System.Single.Parse(_float))) / (float 100)
    result
```

I really hope someone can help me, because this is driving me crazy. Thank you in advance.

**EDIT (16-11-2015)**:

More information after the valid comments, I appreciate all the help and comments.

I have broken the issue down into more "parts" so I've introduced a few conventions for this application. I figured that there is no solution for the problem so I needed to put in some restrictions and hope for the best...

- I get the decimal symbol from `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator` and make sure the column in the excel sheet is of type Number, adding a column of this type and resaving if needed.
- I remove all the other symbols from the string, leaving only the separator in place. (Just like the answer Petr)
- Running Excel in same context and app making sure the `CultureInfo` is the same.

To expand on Petr's answer:

```
let ParseFloat o =
    let decimalSeparator = Convert.ToChar(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator);
    let newv = String((o.ToString()) |> Seq.filter (fun c -> Char.IsNumber c || c = decimalSeparator) |> Array.ofSeq )
    let rslt = match Double.TryParse(newv) with
               | true, number -> (float number)
               | false, _ -> throw "Cannot parse the number"
    rslt
```

Comment: You can use Double.TryParse() overload with different combinations of NumberStyles and Cultures: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s27fasw(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I don't know the Format in advance. Even more, I don't know the format in each sheet. That's why I'm looking for a really general "always" working method

Comment: In this case probably there is no "always" working solution. In some cultures `,` may be thousand divider - in others it used as decimal point. And if the number is written using Chinese numerals?

Comment: You are right of course. I will change the question to: Only , and . deviders

Comment: If you don't know the format in advance, I don't see how this would be possible. Consider this number: `1,701`. Is it *one thousand, seven hundred and one?* Or is it *one point seven oh one?*

Comment: I have updated the answer with a bit more information on the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
open System
let value = "£1,097." 
let newv = String(value |> Seq.filter (fun c -> Char.IsNumber c || c = '.') |> Array.ofSeq )
let rslt = match Double.TryParse(newv) with
           | true, number -> printfn"Converted '%s' to %.2f" value number
           | false, _ -> printfn "Unable to convert '%s'" value
```

Result:

> Converted '£1,097.' to 1097.00

Comment: This is lovely! Works like a charm I just "swap" out the . for a , when there it's running in another culture. Thank you very much and as a side note, great looking code; wrapping that pipe in the ctor, would have never tried that.